# Storing regional (slovenian) characters in the database

Tags: sql-server-2005, character-encoding

This might be painfully obvious to some (most?) of you, however it has been bugging me for a while now.

I have two databases running on the same SQL server (2005). As far as I can see they both have the same language/regional properties. Both have collation set to "Sloveninan_CL_AS" and yet one stores all Slovenian special characters (č, ž, š) without a problem, and the other coverts them to their non-regional sensitive "matches" (c, z, s).

All strings subjected to regional characters in both databases are stored in fields of the same type (varchar).

I am wondering what other settings are there that could affect this behaviour? What additional steps can I take to ensure special characters will be saved correctly in the second database?

**EDIT**: The only additional information that could prove relevant I can think of is that the second ("malfunctioning") database was initially created with a different collation setting and was changed at a later time, whereas the first was (probably) created with the setting set to the current value. However I think, since the setting can be changed, this shouldn't be a problem. Also, the server has been restarted since the collation setting was changed.

Comment: how (client app, sql statement via management studio), where (directly on server, different client pc) and under which OS environment (OS version, regional settings,etc...) does this happen?

Comment: @pastacool this happens in all situations, but it was first noticed through a client app. Because of its oddity I tried it with a sql statement via management studio and directly editing data in the table (Right click on the Table -> Edit). All options produce the same result: characters in one database are stored correctly and in another are "converted"-

Comment: when you did your edits, did you work directly on the server in question or always from the same machine with the same management studio?

Comment: @pastacool that's a good point. Will try to edit data on the server itself through remote desktop connection and report back.

Comment: @pastacool Just tried it, with the same result - characters are converted. (tried editing the table directly in management studio and with a sql query run through management studio)

Comment: @Rekre Why not create a new database without accent sensitivity, change it to accent sensitivity, and then try entering Slovenian letters? :)

Comment: @Rekre: one more thing, is the collation explicitly set on table/field or just comming from the server settings?

Comment: @Rekre: I think **Dave Markle** is on the right track - It's probably that the tables on your *malfunctioning* server are still having the *original* collation. try to script this table and have "use/set collation" active and check which collation setting would be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use the NVARCHAR() datatype instead.  NVARCHAR uses Unicode, which is a lot friendlier when it comes to localization.

Anyway, it's definitely a material issue that the database was initially created with a different collation.  **When you set the collation on a database, what you are actually doing is setting the *default* collation for newly created objects.** Take a look at the tables themselves.  I'm willing to bet that they are still set to the old collation.  You may have to recreate or ALTER the tables and indices in order for the new collation to take effect.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx

Comment: Well that I know, but it isn't really relevant... As far as I can see varchar is perfectly capable of storing characters that I am interested in - it successfully does so on the very same server!

Comment: True enough, but always using Unicode eliminates the need to use default code page and such. Sometimes Slovenian isn't the only language which will fill those columns.  IMO by not using Unicode, you open yourself up to pain.  Just my opinion.

Comment: +1 for MSDN link which explains that collation change of DB does not affect user-defined tables which already exists

Answer (score 1):

Have you definitely changed the collation on the database itself? Not just the column? When I try the following script on a test database and switch the *database* collation back and forth between slovenian and latin I get different results for the `č` character (the `N` prefixed version always works)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @testtable TABLE
(
A VARCHAR(5) COLLATE Slovenian_CI_AS,
B  VARCHAR(5) COLLATE Slovenian_CI_AI
)

INSERT INTO @testtable
VALUES ('čžš','čžš')

INSERT INTO @testtable
VALUES (N'čžš',N'čžš')

SELECT *,CAST(A AS VARBINARY(6)) ,CAST(B AS VARBINARY(6))  
FROM @testtable
```

Slovenian_CI_AS

```
A     B                    
----- ----- -------------- --------------
čžš   čžš   0xE89E9A       0xE89E9A
čžš   čžš   0xE89E9A       0xE89E9A
```

Latin1_General_CI_AS

```
A     B                    
----- ----- -------------- --------------
cžš   cžš   0x639E9A       0x639E9A
čžš   čžš   0xE89E9A       0xE89E9A
```

Comment: You are correct. The database and the table collation ware correctly set to Slovenian_CI_AS , however the **column** collation remained at the previous setting (from before the collation was changed on the database). Thank you!

Comment: @Rekreativc - That was actually Dave Markle's suggestion I thought you might have the opposite problem!